# Why get_full_filename error happens in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, path, save

I want to read all images in specific folder and save it to 64*64 size jpg images.

But the error occur and I don't know why and what to do. 
Pleaes help me

Error code :

```
File "Nikon_D70_0_19458.tif" doesn't exist

Error: imread (line 340) fullname = get_full_filename(filename);

Error: Untitled (line 13) dList(i).data = imread(dList(i).name);
```

My code :

```
clc; clear; close all; 
imgPath = 'C:\Users\LG\Desktop\TIFF\dataset1\60\'; %open image path

dList = dir([imgPath '*.tif']); name = 1; %save name index

for i=1:length(dList) %open image dList(i).data = imread(dList(i).name);
    dList(i).data = dList(i).data(1:256 ,1:256,:); %crop image 256*256
    a = dList(i).data;
    YCbCr = rgb2ycbcr(a);
    Y = YCbCr(:,:,1);
    Cb = YCbCr(:,:,2);
    Cr = YCbCr(:,:,3);
    [height,width] = size(Y);
    for q=1:32:height-32
        for w= 1:32:width-32
            block = Y(q:q+63 , w:w+63);
                Resultados='C:\Users\LG\Desktop\TIFF\training\60'; %save image path
                imwrite(block, fullfile(Resultados, ['SerieN', num2str(i), '.jpg']),'Quality',60) % save image
                name = name+1;
         end
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The field `dList(i).name` does not contain the full path, just the file name. You can get the full path using [`fullfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html):

```
dList(i).data = imread(fullfile(imgPath, dList(i).name));
```